# How to add a HttpResponse to a C# class

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm generating an Excel file and I want to download it like this in my ASP.NET MVC 5 application:

```
var ef = new ExcelFile();
var ws = ef.Worksheets.Add("Worksheet 1");

ef.Save(this.Response, "asd.xlsx");
```

In the last line, it gives error because there is no HttpResponse, how can I add HttpResponse to my class? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. What is the class you are in? What should that code do?

Comment: `HttpResponse `Class is available in `System.Web` namespace, do you have it imported in your code?

Comment: Step 1: Download something, Step 2: ????, Step 3: Save to Excel ... is it just me or is there something missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return a file in ASP.Net MVC5 you can use [the `File` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file(v=vs.118).aspx) in your action :

```
public FileStreamResult MyExcelFile()
{
    // Create your excel filestream

    // ...
    return File(fileStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
}
```